# How to create different rows inside a loop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have an array of images, between other properties, and I am trying to get this result:

[image]

When it reach the end of the container (on a desktop is 4 images and it must addapt to smaller screens) it should create another `div` and insert the images inside it.

If I was working with static data I would do something like this:

```
<div>
   <div className="d-flex products-container justify-content-between mt-5">
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div className="d-flex products-container justify-content-between mt-5">
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
      <div className="border">
         <img src={require('../../assets/images/Products/molde.png')} alt="Produto" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

However the data is coming dynamically from an API and I am using a loop to create the elements:

```
props.products.map(product => {
   return <div className="border">
             <img src={product.img} alt="Produto" />
          </div>
})
```

Because of that I am getting this:

[image]

I tried to use a `if else` statement based on the `index` to determine the behavior but without success.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: is the bootstrap grid out of question?

Comment: Why don't use just use something like this for your classes? `col-xs-6 col-sm-3` This will do 2 columns on mobile and everything above that will have 4 columns. You don't need to separate them into rows as that is automatically handled with the CSS.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Looping through and working with the index value is a good approach. Please revise to show that attempt.

Comment: @imvain2 I did that, however I forgot to set the class `row`. Noob mystakes :) . If you want to transform your comment into an answer I'd be glad to accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's built in grid classes that will automatically create columns depending on what classes you use.

Using `col-xs-6 col-sm-3` will do 2 columns on mobile and everything above that will have 4 columns.

You don't need to separate them into rows as that is automatically handled with the CSS.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

Comment: Just to clarify (and it is in the bootstrap documentation) the col-xs-6 col-sm-3 should be a class in the div.  So <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3'><img file /></div> and just loop through all images.

Comment: @user3520445, each image should be wrapped in a div with those classes. And you don't have to worry about grouping 4 images together and wrapping by a div with `row`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this may restrict the use of some flexbox features that Bootstrap offers.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way, but working with index seems like a good approach. Something like this might work:

```
props.products.map((product, index) => {
   if (index + 1 % 4 === 0) { // index plus one is evenly divisible by 4
       return <div className="border">
             <img src={product.img} alt="Produto" />
          </div>
       </div>

       <div className="d-flex products-container justify-content-between mt-5">
    } else {
       return <div className="border">
             <img src={product.img} alt="Produto" />
          </div>
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe make one of your CSS class settings `style="display:inline-block"`.

Try this to provide inline CSS in every block: `style="display:block"`.

Comment: This doesn't address the need to have four elements on each row.